# In Fogbugz, how can I create a chart that displays "time remaining" for a given milestone, *including* all its dependent milestones?

Tags: fogbugz

My team is mimicking [sprints](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_%28development%29#Sprint) with a hierarchy of milestones in Fogbugz.  We have our main delivery deadline called the "R0" milestone.  This milestone is dependent on a bunch of sprint milestones.  The R0 milestone is treated as our ["backlog"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_%28development%29#Product_Backlog), but we change the milestone to the current sprint milestone when we schedule that work for the current sprint.

When we want to extract the "time remaining" for each developer for milestone "R0", we want to include all the "R0" tasks *as well as* all the tasks which are in child sprint milestones that "R0" is dependent on.

I have a workaround of doing a massive update on the database that creates a tag for all stories in "R0" and all the sprints, but I have to keep manually updating it.

Is there a better way to do this task so I can give the managers a simple URL instead of having to generate this report myself, everytime it is requested?

NOTE:
I know that there is a Fogbugz Stack Exchange site, but they seem to have locked-down the asking of new questions, which is why I'm asking this question here.